# Postgres: some process is cleaning all my table records

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres installed in a Centos and another application is using Postgres the save data.

For sometime, and I can't find the reason, all the database tables become empty on the weekends.

I have been searching a lot to try to find some clues of the reason of that behaviour, but logs are not giving me that info.
I am pretty sure the application is not executing anything to clean the records, my thoughts are pointing to some process for some reason in the Postgres side.

The pg_log only shows this warning the day it happens:

> HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
> LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (11 seconds apart)

Apart from that I have no other clues.
Performing a VACUUM ANALYZE VERBOSE it says there is no dead data so it has nothing to delete.

Can you tell me what should I look to get the reason? Should it be any Postgres process to do it?

Comment: Postgres does not delete data on its own. It must be some process outside of Postgres (a cron job or something similar) or maybe you simply forget to commit everything. But anyway: it's not something _inside_ Postgres, but in your environment. And that's impossible to answer or debug from here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "*what should I look to get the reason?*" is an answerable question though, like turning on statement logs

Comment: @Bergi: not really. Do _you_ now her/his environment and all possible applications or cron jobs accessing the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't know the environment, but isn't it possible to utilise postgres to *find* the applications accessing it?

Comment: I thought the same, postgres was not the problem source, but I can ensure there is no crontab task regarding the database, I looked elsewhere and I didn't find anything. There is only one app using Postgres, and it is Avaya Telephony System, and where is no way Avaya is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> LOG: checkpoints are occurring too frequently (11 seconds apart)

This log message should also include all the information log_line_prefix tells it to include.  So you should set log_line_prefix to include more information, like application name (voluntarily supplied by the client), database username, and host name/IP from which the connection came.

But perhaps more directly at issue, if things are connecting to your database and doing things you don't understand or approve of, it is time to change your passwords.

Comment: Apart from this messages there is nothing in the /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log folder. In this folder are created the log corresponding to each week day, and I only see plenty of those warnings in the log of the day I loose the data.